# Connected Space VS Connected Components

Tags: general-topology

By definition a topologic space $X$ is connected $\iff$ there are **no** $U,V\subseteq X$, such that both are open, disjoint and non empty.

On the other hand, by [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Connected_components): "The components of any topological space X form a partition of X: they are disjoint, non-empty, and their union is the whole space"

So we can say in general that a topologic space $X$ is connected if the cover can be build by connected components? It seems a bit like recursive defination

Comment: Your definition of connectedness is wrong. The intervals $(0,1)$ and $(2,3)$ in $\mathbb R$ are open, disjoint and non-empty, yet $\mathbb R$ is connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A topological space is connected iff we cannot write it as $X=U \cup V$ where $U \cap V = \emptyset$, both $U,V \neq \emptyset$ and $U,V$ are both open.

This definition also applies to subspaces of any space $X$, a subspace $A$ is connected iff it is a connected space (in its own right) in the subspace topology from $X$.

A space $X$ that is not connected can still have many connected subspaces $A$. E.g. $\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$ is not connected ($U= (-\infty,0), V = (0,+\infty)$ disconnect it) but $(0,1)$ is a connected subspace of it and $(1,2)$ too. The maximal connected subspaces of $X$ ($A$ is connected and a strict superset of $A$ is not) is a component of $X$. So there is nothing circular about that.

For $x \in X$ consider $\mathcal{C}_x = \{C \subseteq X\mid C \text{ connected and } x \in C\}$ which is always nonempty as $\{x\}$ is connected in any space and contains $x$. Its union $C_x$ is connected by a standard theorem (because all members intersect in $x$) and if $C$ is connected and $C_x \subseteq C$ then by definition $C \in \mathcal{C}$ and so $C \subseteq C_x$ and so $C=C_x$ so $C_x$ is a maximal connected subspace of $X$ and so a component of $X$.

We then observe that for $x \neq y$ in $X$ the sets $C_x$ and $C_y$ (thus constructed) obey $$C_x = C_y \text{ or } C_x \cap C_y = \emptyset$$

which explains the remark in the text that components form a disjoint partition of $X$.

The components of $\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$ are precisely the $U$ and $V$ that disconnected it (they are connected and maximally so). A space can have *one* component (when it is already connected) or uncountably many ones too (in the irrationals the components are the singletons).

Answer (score 1):

To try to give a brief outline that might help you organise the notions:

1. First of all, one considers the general notion of *connectedness* applicable to arbitrary topological spaces. The definition is indeed as you have mentioned it and a space is to be called "connected" whenever it enjoys the particular property delineated in the definition.
2. Now that one has a general concept of what it means for an arbitrary topological space to be connected, one can consequently consider those arbitrary *subsets* $M \subseteq X$ of a certain fixed topological space $(X, \mathscr{T})$ which become themselves connected spaces when equipped with *the subspace topology*. In general, a topological space can very well fail to be connected and still have connected subsets: the empty subset and its singletons are always connected.
3. Having acquired the perspective of 2), one can proceed to equip the set of all connected subsets of $(X, \mathscr{T})$ with inclusion and thus regard it as an ordered set. One natural question in this context is "do there exist maximal elements in this set and if so what can be said about them?". It turns out that not only do these maximal elements exist, the ordered set in question is inductive (i.e. it is of that special kind to which Zorn's lemma can be applied) and the maximal elements yield a *partition* of the parent set $X$.
4. On a related note, one can also consider the following binary relation on $X$, according to which two generic elements $x, y \in X$ are related if they both belong to one and the same *connected* subset of $X$. It turns out remarkably that this is actually an equivalence relation and that its classes are identical to the maximal connected subsets mentioned above at 3).

Having thus obtained two equivalent -- but of somewhat differing perspectives -- descriptions of this collection of maximal connected subsets, one agrees to call them the "connected components" of the ambient space $(X, \mathscr{T})$ (they do constitute a partition of the support set $X$ alone however they are determined by the topology $\mathscr{T}$ -- changing the topology on one and the same support set may very well have the effect of altering the connected components -- and therefore in full rigour it is appropriate to refer to them as connected components of the whole space, not just of the support set $X$).

The space $(X, \mathscr{T})$ is itself connected if and only if it has only one connected component (namely $X$ itself) if and only if the equivalence relation introduced at 4) is equal to the maximum equivalence on $X$, namely $X \times X$.

Comment: Zorn is overkill. Just take the union of all connected subsets that contain a given point. Etc. See my answer. Entirely constructive.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma With all due to respect to you and your answer -- which may I say I also find very educating and solid -- my reason for mentioning Zorn's lemma was as an indirect device that would do away with the need to actually define inductively ordered sets (I didn't want to go that fully into details). I did not mean to imply that Zorn's lemma is in any way at play in proving the existence of the connected components (and I regret it if it comes across in this unwanted manner). I just wanted to point out the fact that the connected subsets under inclusion form an inductive set.

Comment: I’d say: don’t mention inductive partial orders if you don’t intend to use Zorn...

Comment: @Henno Brandsma Your opinion is noted sir, but may I reserve the due privilege of emphasising the fact that an ordered set is inductive whenever I might have the inclination to do so. It is a valid structural observation and in no way will it cause any harm.